# Не работает batch-скрипт, хотя в командной строке команды работают адекватно

Tags: windows, cmd, командная-строка, bat

Есть простенький пакетный скрипт с командами вида:

```
move "c:\folder_1" "c:\folder_2"
```

Он не работает, хотя если просто копировать команды в командную строку, то они адекватно отрабатывают и переносят папки куда надо. Вывод под каждой командой после запуска скрипта:

```
Не удается найти указанный файл.
```

В чем может быть проблема? Пробовал расширения и .cmd и .bat, результат один и тот же.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, я понял. Кодировка файла с кодом должна быть Cyrillic (Windows 866).

Answer (score 1):

Можно сменить кодировку:

```
chcp 65001    <- UTF-8
chcp 1251     <- Windows-1251 (стандартная кириллическая)
chcp 866      <- Windows-866 (стандартная для cmd.exe)
```

Comment: Перепробовал эти кодировки, но это не помогло. Потом я решил проверить перенос каталогов без нижнего подчеркивания в названии, и все заработало. Это нормально, когда скрипт не видит нижние подчеркивания? Конечно, можно переименовать каталоги в что-то вроде "newFolder", но у меня их почти сотня, да и названия так читать удобнее.

Comment: Это нужно написать в баткике перед мувом, в зависимоти от кодировки батника. Это должно работать. Я не могу проверить сечас, у меня Linux.